# Odd behavior from raphaelJS when trying to move SVG rects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, svg, raphael

I am working on a graphics demo using RaphaelJS and jQuery.SVG. Right now I have a dynamically created 8x8 grid of rectangles that users are able to click to select. Once two of the rects are selected, then the selected rects are supposed to switch places with each other (like in Bejeweled.)

I have gotten to the point where I can get the rects to swap, but they are not ending up in the correct positions. According to the code, I am swapping out the x and y coordinates of each selected rect in an animate function. The rects always end up "off the grid" in testing. The visual effect is pretty neat, but I really want the rects to stay lined up.

http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/2222/raphaelerror.jpg

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/593/raphaelerror2.jpg/

The debug strings that I am building tell me that the positions of the rects have not changed. Obviously that is not true...what is going on here?

Here's the relevant code for this issue:

```
        // swapTiles
/*

Swaps two tiles on the board that have been set to 'selected' with an animation.    

*/
function swapTiles(toSwap) {

    var holdX = $(toSwap[0]).attr('x');
    var holdY = $(toSwap[0]).attr('y');

    // Pre-swap debugging
    statusString += "<br><b>BEFORE SWAP</b><br>";
    statusString += "<br>First cell: " + selectedCellNames[0];
    statusString += "<br>2nd cell: " + selectedCellNames[1];
    statusString += "<br>$(toSwap[0]).attr('x'): " + $(toSwap[0]).attr('x').toString();
    statusString += "<br>$(toSwap[0]).attr('y'): " + $(toSwap[0]).attr('y').toString();
    statusString += "<br>$(toSwap[1]).attr('x'): " + $(toSwap[1]).attr('x').toString();
    statusString += "<br>$(toSwap[1]).attr('y'): " + $(toSwap[1]).attr('y').toString();
    statusString += "<br>";

    /*
    This line is using jQuery SVG to grab the DOM elements. This is being used because trying to grab the elements through
    raphael was returning undefined errors. There seems to be some DOM scope issue that is causing me to use this and the temp.node 
    workarounds in order to reference SVG objects created through raphael.

    What did not work:

    $(toSwap[0]).animate({ x: 50, y: 100, 'stroke-width': 3 }, 250, '<'); --raphael animate function
    $(toSwap[0]).node.animate({ x: 50, y: 100, 'stroke-width': 3 }, 250, '<'); 

    When I tried to access the tiles using jQuery and the cellName user-defined attribute, I got '0' added to my debug output.        

    */
    $(toSwap[0]).animate({ svgX: $(toSwap[1]).attr('x'), svgY: $(toSwap[1]).attr('y'), svgStrokeWidth: 2, svgStroke: "#000" }, 250);
    $(toSwap[1]).animate({ svgX: holdX, svgY: holdY, svgStrokeWidth: 2, svgStroke: "#000" }, 250);

    // Post-swap debugging
    statusString += "<br><b>SWAP COMPLETE</b><br>";        
    statusString += "<br>$(toSwap[0]).attr('x'): " + $(toSwap[0]).attr('x').toString();
    statusString += "<br>$(toSwap[0]).attr('y'): " + $(toSwap[0]).attr('y').toString();
    statusString += "<br>$(toSwap[1]).attr('x'): " + $(toSwap[1]).attr('x').toString();
    statusString += "<br>$(toSwap[1]).attr('y'): " + $(toSwap[1]).attr('y').toString();
    statusString += "<br>";

}

// drawRect
/*

returns a Raphael rectangle object with the inputted options
color = the value that the color attr will be set to for this rect
x, y = x & y position of the top-left corner of the rect
w, h = width and height of the rect
corner = radius for the rounded corners

*/
function drawRect(color, x, y, w, h, corner) {

    var temp = canvas.rect(x, y, w, h, corner);
    temp.attr("fill", color);
    temp.node.setAttribute("selected", "false"); // Will be used to check for selected tiles in main loop    
    temp.node.setAttribute("cellName", cellName); // Give this rect a name

    // Add the mouseover/hover events
    temp.node.onmouseover = function () {

        temp.animate({ scale: 1.5, stroke: "#FFF", 'stroke-width': 3 }, 250, 'bounce').toFront();

    }; // end temp.node.onmouseover

    temp.node.onmouseout = function () {

        if (temp.node.getAttribute("selected") == "true") {

            temp.animate({ scale: 1, stroke: "#FFF", 'stroke-width': 4 }, 250, 'elastic').toFront();

        }
        else {

            temp.animate({ scale: 1, stroke: "#000", 'stroke-width': 2 }, 250, 'elastic').toBack();

        }

        // Update the status debugging
        statusString += "<br>(x: " + x.toString() + ", y: " + y.toString() + ") temp.node.getAttribute('selected') after .node.onmouseout = " + temp.node.getAttribute("selected");
        statusString += "<br>selectedCount = " + selectedCount.toString();
        statusString += "<br>cellName = " + temp.node.getAttribute("cellName");
        statusString += "<br>selectedCells[0] = " + selectedCells[0].toString();
        statusString += "<br>selectedCells[1] = " + selectedCells[1].toString();
        $("#status").html(statusString);
        statusString = "";

    }; // end temp.node.onmouseout

    // Toggle between selected / not-selected
    temp.node.onclick = function () {

        // if not selected yet 
        if (temp.node.getAttribute("selected") != "true") {

            temp.animate({ scale: 1, stroke: "#FFF", 'stroke-width': 4 }, 250, 'elastic').toFront();
            temp.node.setAttribute("selected", "true");
            selectedCount += 1;

            // Place the current cell into our array
            if (selectedCount == 1) {

                selectedCells[0] = temp.node;
                selectedCellNames[0] = temp.node.getAttribute("cellName");

            }
            // We have two cells selected: time to swap
            else if (selectedCount == 2) {

                selectedCells[1] = temp.node;
                selectedCellNames[1] = temp.node.getAttribute("cellName");

                swapTiles(selectedCells);

                // Clean up selectedCells and the selected attributes
                /*

                Since selectedCells already contains references to the temp.nodes of each SVG object, 
                use this format to set the attributes. No jQuery SVG call or additional .node is needed.

                */
                selectedCells[0].setAttribute("selected", "false");
                selectedCells[1].setAttribute("selected", "false");

                selectedCells[0] = "";
                selectedCells[1] = "";

                selectedCellNames[0] = "";
                selectedCellNames[1] = "";

                selectedCount = 0;

            }
            else {
                // Something went wrong
                statusString += "<br><b>ERROR: selectedCells out of range!</b>";
            }


        }
        // if already selected de-select
        else {

            temp.animate({ scale: 1, stroke: "#000", 'stroke-width': 2 }, 250, 'elastic').toBack();
            temp.node.setAttribute("selected", "false");
            selectedCount -= 1;

            // Remove the current cell name from our array
            if (selectedCount == 0) {

                selectedCells[0] = "";
                selectedCellNames[0] = "";

            }
            else if (selectedCount == 1) {

                selectedCells[1] = "";
                selectedCellNames[1] = "";

            }
            else {
                // Something went wrong
                statusString += "<br><b>ERROR: selectedCells out of range!</b>";
            }

        }

        // Update the status debugging
        statusString += "<br>(x: " + x.toString() + ", y: " + y.toString() + ") temp.node.getAttribute('selected') after .node.onclick = " + temp.node.getAttribute("selected");
        statusString += "<br>selectedCount = " + selectedCount.toString();
        statusString += "<br>selectedCells[0] = " + selectedCells[0].toString();
        statusString += "<br>selectedCells[1] = " + selectedCells[1].toString();
        $("#status").html(statusString);
        statusString = "";

    }; // end temp.node.onclick        

    return temp;

    /*

    NOTES:

    temp.node.[function] - the node raphael property lets me directly access the DOM element that I just created

    I will need to add all of my onclick and other direct access events for my tiles in this function.
    I will get errors if I try to reference the DOM elements from another part of this program, probably because it is only
    in this function that I actually create the DOM object. Once this function finishes, then the temp object reference is passed 
    back into my initialization loop, where at that point I cannot add any more DOM elements. 

    .animate - Raphael's animation function. Note that the properties that are animated are defined in the first argument,
    between a set of {}. The second argument is the time in milliseconds that the animation will take.

    .toFront() & .toBack() - These functions move the object to the top or bottom of the drawing stack. In other words, if I use 
    toFront on an object, it should be drawn on top of everything else, and vice-versa. This eliminates a graphical issue where the 
    tiles overrlap while expanded.

    .node.setAttribute / .getAttribute(key, value) - These are the DOM functions to set and get attributes of specific DOM elements.
    I am using these instead of .attr(attr, value) because I can't perform jQuery operations on the DOM elements at this point in the script.

    */

} // end drawRect

// Initialize the grid of rectangles
for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {

        cellName = "cell " + i + ":" + j;

        // drawRect(color, x, y, width, height, corner radius)
        grid[i][j] = drawRect(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)], startx + (width * j), starty + (height * i), width, height, cornerRadius);

        // used for debugging
        debugString += "<br>grid[" + i + "][" + j + "] x: " + (startx + (width * j)) + " y: " + (starty + (height * i));

    } // end inner for loop


} // end outer for loop
```

I'm not a Javascript expert so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The plot thickens:

The "x" and "y" attributes of my dynamically-generated Raphael/SVG object change by a very small amount each time that they are clicked. I have no clue why this is happening (there is definitely no code that I wrote that does that!) This must be some sort of Raphael bug.

Also, if I try to access the "x" or "y" attributes of my cells, say, by using 
[code]
debugString += "<br>grid[" + i + "][" + j + "] x: " + $(grid[i][j]).attr("x") + " y: " + $(grid[i][j]).attr("y");
[/code]

my debugString will print out "x: undefined y: undefined"

So I can't access the x or y attrs...

Comment: Outside of my drawRect function. I can't figure out why I can't get the x and y attributes of my Raphael objects to:

a. Stay the same when I click on them
b. Be defined outside of the function where they are declared.
c. Change the values correctly (see the 2nd screenshot above.)

Can anyone provide help on this?

Comment: Here are the full source files for this project. I hope that someone can steer me in the right direction on this, since I am truly stuck.

http://www.mikehuttman.com/Match3Source.zip

Comment: have you resolved this issue... I am trying to implement a similar swap functionality and got stuck